# System ruby/gem vs RVM ruby/gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I installed **RVM**, read the documentation and do not understand it well. For example, I had an rails application that is created and run just find (before I install RVM) and it uses the system ruby and system gem. Now after I install RVM:

1. Do I need to re-install these gems into RVM so these gem can be under RVM control?
2. How to a port the application to use RVM gem instead of system gem?
3. Is RVM a wrapper for ruby and gem or a separate repository of these ruby and gem? So if I install a gem under RVM, the gem only exist in RVM or exist across RVM and system, or vice versa. Am I duplicating or does RVM and System synchronize their gem/system themselves?

I am still completely confused of the goods and uses of RVM. Now all my previous applications that used to work not doesn't even start with various errors.

My environment: Mac OS X 10.8; Rails 3.2.9; TextMate

Comment: Comment on the down-vote perhaps? I've been working with rails for 5 years to ask this question that I need an answer for. Or do I get down-voted for questioning RVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. Use [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) and there will be no pain.
2. It just need to be run in RVM environment.  No special porting required.
3. It is intended to provide separate environment for each of your projects by substituting environment variables like $PATH, $GEM_HOME, $GEM_PATH.

Pros:

1. You can have different ruby interpreters installed to fulfil your applications' requirements.  Imagine that you are starting a new project with Rails 1.9.3, but you are still working on old two which use 1.8.7 and 1.9.1 and have not been ported so far.
2. Your gems does not conflict with each other.  For example Psych has special needs.  If you use it, you got to use it in all your project.  But with RVM you can create different gemsets for each project.
3. Moves gem directories too dirs where you got read+write access.  This is good because does not force you to compile gems with root privileges.

Cons:

1. I had problems with RVM when using it for long time under Fish shell.  Two times, after some weeks whole RVM went crazy and just get broken.  Not going into details, I got to remove whole `~/.rvm` directory.  Never happened under Bash.

My typical workflow with RVM is following:

1. Add `ruby "1.9.3"` or equivalent to Gemfiles of my projects to avoid running it with wrong Ruby version.
2. Install RVM and install Rubies I need, `rvm install 1.9.3`.
3. In given project, `rvm use 1.9.3`.
4. Install required gems.
5. Use my app normally.

Please note I am not using Gemsets.  This is because of Cons #1.  I really love Fish shell, can't live without it, and bundler alone gives me decent management of Gems (one problem: Psych).  To use Gemsets, two additional steps between 3. and 4.:

3a. Create one `rvm gemset create gemset1`.
3b. Use it `rvm use gemset1@1.9.3`.

I always use RVM when working with some legacy projects.

Refer to this screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm for decent tutorial.

Comment: When I switched to fish I started using rbenv also. No problems, and if you use Bundler then no problems with gemsets also.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier – Thanks to your comment I'm using fish+rbenv for half a year and I'm really satisfied with it. There are some gotchas, but hints provided [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/195) helped.